# Growth rate exponential function

Tags: exponential-function

This might be very trivial, but I want to make sure I get this right: If I have 2 rats growing to 1000 in a year, then what is the growth rate per year?

My take:

$\frac{1000-2}{2}=498 \cdot 100 = 49800 = 498\%$

Is this correct?

Comment: Well, since you mention (and tag) exponential functions, I would have thought the question was asking you about the function $r(t)$, the number of rats at time $t$.  We are told $r(0)=2$ and $r(1)=1000$ and you could try to write the function in exponential form, as $r(t)=ce^{rt}$ for constants $c,r$.  The problem is then asking you what $r$ is.

Comment: Hmm, I have a to points (0,2) and (365,1000). Then I make a function: f(x) = 2*(1,02)^x and then I'm asked to find the growth rate. Isn't that an exponetial function?

Comment: @AmyA: What exactly do you mean by the growth rate? Is it the percentage by which the rats are growing every day, or in a year?

Comment: Growth rate In a year

Comment: I would have thought the growth rate was what I said.    If you have some other definition you would like to use here, please edit your post to provide it.

Comment: Also, please indicate the units of time you want your function to use.  In my first comment I assumed you were using years, but of course you never specified anything.  In your comment it appears that you may be using days.  Any unit you like is fine, but you do need to specify.